# main () std::string instead of char** why the exclusion

Tags: c++

The compiler gives the  warning
`warning: second argument of ‘int main(int, std::string*)’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]`

when I choose to put in

`int main(int argv, std::string a[])`

instead of

`int main(int argv, char * argc [])`

If you can come up with a reason ,also pray dotell what's wrong with the string approach.

I mean with std::string being the posterchild of of character representation/string representation , for C++ , why bother with C styles?

**ALSO**

IS there really no hack around the standard implementation?

Comment: Because `main()` is not allowed to have an `std::string` parameter in standards compliant code. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function).

Comment: Spoiler alert: The names "argv" and "argc" actually *mean* something, and there's a reason they're usually used in a specific order.

Comment: "IS there a reason why the compiler gives the warning" - well, what do you think? The compiler emits warnings just for fun, without any reason, just to annoy you? (you'd deserve it, but still...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I think the compiler, though an awesome piece of code , is still non learning piece of code ..and cannot be imagined to handle very possible input ..so I just thought maybe it just fudged up.

Comment: @nerorevenge: You don't need a "learning" compiler to deal with incorrect code. It's just following the rules of the language (but do look up "internal compiler errors", which are a *rare* class of errors that are due to a bug in the compiler itself).

Comment: (How the heck did this c**p get to +2???)

Comment: @H2CO3 I guess there are more newbies reading such questions than you previously thought and I suppose people forget you only upvote to show signs of honoring the fact the person has researched the question well.

Comment: @nerorevenge Still, this is not a great question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple: the language rules do not mandate your form and the implementation you use do not support it through its own choice.

Quoting the standard  3.6.1p2

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
```

> and

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> In the latter form argc shall be the number of arguments passed to the program from the environment in which the program is run. If argc is nonzero these arguments shall be supplied in argv[0] through argv[argc-1] as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated multibyte strings (NTMBSs) (17.3.2.1.3.2) and argv[0] shall be the pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the name used to invoke the program or "". The value of argc shall be nonnegative. The value of argv[argc] shall be 0. [Note: it is recommended that any further (optional) parameters be added after argv. ]

EDIT: to cover additional question:

There is no need to "hack" anything, as nothing stops to use a function or a class that takes the original argc and argv and processes it to a vector literally, or better yet parse it and map processed data to internal variables.  We have a plenty of those floating around, and those who create more than a handful of main()-s per year probably already use one of those or their own.

Comment: Well put.Any reason to as to why it is implemented as such? I mean if std::string is available and is the c++ posterchild for string representation , why bother with char?

Comment: Yes, the std::string is a C++ type and more difficult for operating systems to implement.  Remember, the operating system is passing information to your function via the `main` function.  An array of pointers to nul terminated strings is easy for an OS to implement and pass.  This also lets the OS use one function to call yours, whether it is implemented in C++ or C; remember C does not have `std::string`.

Comment: The mandated forms are inherited from C. And for extending the main functions there were just no proposals. I guess for lack of good motivation, the way we have works fine as is, and in practice most users have libraries and frameworks to process the command line anyway.

Comment: `std::string` is a *dynamic string*. It's not the panacea for each and every string-type situation. Command-line arguments are a perfect example for a *non*-dynamic string where `std::string` would be plain overdoing it.

Comment: I don't think there are many implementations these days where `main` is called directly by the operating system, instead of intermediate code provided by the compiler. Of course it would be wasteful if the OS provided arguments would be first copied into `std::string`s before handing them to `main`.

Comment: @nerorevenge The reason is that `std::string` is not part of the C++ language. It's not in the core. It's not a built-in, just a class in the standard library. And the compiler, the runtime, the caller of `main()` etc. all have no knowledge of its existence at all.

Comment: There are two main reasons why you cannot use `std::string` in the parameter list of `main`, in addition to that mentioned by Balog Pal.

Firstly, `std::string` is not part of the c++ language, it is part of the STL, which is built WITH the c++ language. Secondly, c++ is required to be backwards compatible with the c language, which the STL is not.

Comment: @RobbieE Only half of the two reasonings are valid, namely that `std::string` is not part of the C++ language. But it's not part of STL either, it's part of the C++ standard library. And C++ is not required to be backwards-compatible with C, but at least whoever required that has been very unsuccessful in doing so, because they **aren't.**

Comment: @RobbieE: The standard library is very much part of the C++ language. It may not be part of the language *core*, sure, but it's in the C++ language standard. Also, C++ is not required to (nor is it) backward compatible.

Answer (score 8):

Workaround:

```
 vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc);

 for (auto s: args) 
      cout << s << endl;
```

`std::string` and `std::vector` are heavy weight objects.  Dynamic memory allocation is used during their construction.

2nd way to do it is to use [my RO library](http://volnitsky.com/project/ro/).  Below code will create light weight **iterator range** object around `argv` array:

```
 auto args = ro::range(argv,argv+argc);

 for (auto s: args) 
      cout << s << endl;
```

Comment: I would +1 this if it didn't have the abominable `abusing namespace std;`.

Comment: Teaching rookies bad practices is even worse! They don't have the mental power to see through the bad parts of your advice :-(

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky That's not an excuse, in fact KerrekSB is right and encouraging newcomers to use bad practices is a serious error. Fixed the namespace abuse, but you don't get my upvote for this very reason.

Comment: @H2CO3: note that there's no consensus on which form is good or abomination, when vector and string is involved.  "And is it any wonder/That the monkey's confused"

Comment: Thanks H2CO3, but I prefer examples without namespace. I am reverting your edit.  I am sure readers of this post won't get confused about what `string` I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You've been given the reason why your implementation *need* not support it. However there's also a reason why your implementation would not *want* to support it:

The (usually precompiled) code calling `main` passes an `int` and a `char**` (and in some implementations as extension a second `char**`; indeed, on many platforms it gets exactly that data already provided by the operating system and just passes it on). It is easy to support to ignore trailing arguments (usually they are pushed to the stack in reverse order, so ignoring the additional arguments just means not accessing them, no additional logic required). However, you cannot just read out a `char**` as `std::string*`, therefore the compiler would have to generate extra code to support this interface. Given that any source code using that interface would be non-portable anyway and few people would use it, and given that the original interface works just fine, it would just be a waste of resources to implement that alternative interface.