# Why does modern C++ still retain the old C style prototype for main with int argc, char** argv

Tags: c++

Other than backward compatibility, is there any specific reason for not changing the prototype and benefit from modern features of C++?

Modern C++ encourages the use of value semantics.

Why should argv still be a char array with pointer semantics, which could possible lead to issues if not properly handled?

In Java we have the class with, `void main(String[] args)`.

Am I missing anything fundamental?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [main () std::string instead of char\*\* why the exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393842/main-stdstring-instead-of-char-why-the-exclusion)

Comment: there are c++ programs being written that for some reason do not use `std::string` or `std::vector`. Actually I dont think it would solve that many issues

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);` on the first line of main does that.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Or `std::vector<std::string_view>` for the common case where you don't modify the arguments.

Comment: @Rakete1111: The problem with that is that `span` is a view - what would you use to initialize it with? `string_view` can be initialized from `argv[i]`, so `std::vector<std::string_view>(argv, argv+argc)` constructs an array of `string_view`, but `span<string_view>` won't construct any `string_view`.

Comment: @MSalters oh yeah, that's true. Tried too hard to be funny :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Other than backward compatibility

This is the reason and considered most important in moving forwards with C++.

But there is a proposal: [A Modern C++ Signature for main](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0781r0.html)

Comment: It wouln't be that much of a problem to allow an alternate `main()` declaration - we already allow two different ones, a third doesn't do structual harm, but could become the new default. Though it would probably take two standard seasons to decide on minor details of which type to be passed.

Comment: @peterchen actually it would, the mechanisms for supporting main are... interesting at best. This is actually more of a linking issue than a runtime issue to be honest.

Comment: @Mgetz: convince me :)

Comment: @peterchen first and foremost `main` is treated as if it was C linkage even when not declared so. Second `argv` is editable... yes that's right you can modify those strings. Moreover to make this more fun, none of the parameters can require cleanup. Using `std::string` by value would require that the callee be in on the bargain etc.

Comment: "C linkage"; in this context would mean the linker can call main, and doesn't have to decide which overload is there? What about: when *compiler* encounters a "modern main", it provides an old-style main that forwards to modern main. A modern main passing an immutable command line would likely be acceptable, it could be an opaque type guaranteeing read-only iteration (though I don't see much problem with cleanup when forwarding from old main)

Comment: @peterchen that would violate ODR

Comment: @mgetz: only if "old main" was defined explicitely and implicitely - which should be flagged as error.

Answer (score 0):

Many systems contain code written in languages other than C++.  While it would be possible to have the main entry-point function in user code accept C++ string parameters and then have an implementation-supplied wrapper which translates the underlying platform's arguments into C++ strings and then passes them to the user-code entry point, this would only be advantageous in cases where the underlying environment represented strings in some fashion other than zero-terminated sequences of characters, and where the wrapper would be able to avoid having to first translate to C-style strings before translating into C++ strings.  Otherwise, anything that could be done by the wrapper could be done just as well by user code.